# Ivalid response for preflight (401) when trying to get json from webservice

Tags: ajax, json, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I spent my last 5 working hours searching for this problem, but none of the solutions have helped me, so here goes:

I have an asmx webservice returning JSON

```vb
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
   <Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetObjectsByObjectType(ByVal ObjectType As String)
    Dim db As New Database(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strConnectionStr"))
    Return GetJson(DirectCast(db.ExecuteSelect("##queryHere##"), DataSet).Tables(0))
End Function

Public Function GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String
    Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(From dr As DataRow In dt.Rows Select dt.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().ToDictionary(Function(col) col.ColumnName, Function(col) dr(col)))
End Function
```

This is hosted on a server (and works fine if I use it directly on the server) and I'm trying to access it from my localhost test-server like this

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://linkToServer/DatabaseService.asmx/GetObjectsByObjectType",
    data: JSON.stringify({ stuff }),
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 3000,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorthrown) {
        console.log(errorthrown);
    }
});
```

But i always end up getting either an instant **timeout** response or

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...]. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

I already tried the following:

- setting **crossDomain: true**
- supplying credentials with **username: .., password: ..**
- setting the following server-side:

```js
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

(not sure about the formatting, but they are set correctly, I just didnt want to copy the web.config xml stuff)

- and lots of other small changes, setting-wise

The only working solution I found was this:

If I remove the

```js
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

from the ajax request, I get my JSON result wrapped in a XML document, which I could parse, but I would rather have the JSON directly.

So do you have any idea how I can set thing up, so I can get the JSON result?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you get any solution?